# Multiple HTTP GET parameters into array

Tags: php, http, url

I want to pass multiple parameters numbers via url like this:

> http://myserver.com/myscript.php?param=55311&param=352213&param=6214

(it might be formatted with other way, this is only example)

Now, how to put these parameters (numbers) into array in php code? Like this:

> $param = array('55311', '352213', '6214');

Comment: why not make a seperator like this: http://myserver.com/myscript.php?param=55311_352213_6214 and then explode it?

Comment: I am very beginner with php, how to explode that?

Comment: `$paramArr = explode('_', $_GET['param'])`

Comment: thank you. I didn't know it's that easy

Answer (score 2):

You could use/format your url this way and turn it into a grouping index:

```
param[]=value
```

So this turns into:

```
http://myserver.com/myscript.php?param[]=55311&param[]=352213&param[]=6214
```

So in PHP, you could process them thru `$_GET`:

```
if(isset($_GET['param'])) {
    $param = $_GET['param']; // this in returns an array of those values
}
```

Comment: Back in the mists of time I remember being told that such indexing wasn't strictly speaking allowed in URLs, though PHP seems to handle it OK..?  And should the square brackets be URL encoded?

Comment: @RobBaillie no you do not need to encode it, just put them as is: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Hq82rv?param[]=1&param[]=2&param[]=3

Comment: `?param[]=55311&param[]=352213&param[]=6214` it doesn't looks nice, i think this is better `?param=55311_352213_6214 ` but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but currently I found this solution, maybe helpfull for other.

```
?params['number1']=12345&params['name1']='Hello'
```

In PHP I get this..

```
if(isset($_GET['params'])) {
    $params = (array) $_GET['params']; 
}
```

Use this variables a little bit tricky. Please hava a look at this array index "'number1'" with two kinds of string chars.

```
echo $params["'number1'"] // => 12345
echo $params["'name1'"] // => Hello
```

But I get a nice kind of documented array items.